# ActiveReports - Fetch data firing too many times

Tags: c#, activereports

I have a main report and one sub report.

// Main report calling subReport

```
DataView dvDetails = new DataView(_dtDetails); // _dtDetails is a datatable
rptSubHistory rptSubHistory = new rptSubHistory(dvDetails);
rptSubHistory.DataSource = dvDetails;
subHistory.Report = rptSubHistory;
```

// Fetch data from sub report

```
public void rptSubHistory_FetchData(object sender, GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReport.FetchEventArgs eArgs)
  {
       _intRecordCount++;
  }
```

// Detail format from sub report

```
 public void Detail_Format(object sender, System.EventArgs eArgs)
  {
      if (_dvDetails.Count > 0)
      {
          txtColumn.Text = _dvDetails.Table.Rows[_intRecordCount]["ColumnName"].ToString();
          txtOrigValue.Text = _dvDetails.Table.Rows[_intRecordCount]["OrigValue"].ToString();
          txtNewValue.Text = _dvDetails.Table.Rows[_intRecordCount]["CurrentValue"].ToString();
      }
  }
```

The issue that I'm having is that when the main report is calling the sub report, fetch data from the sub report is iterating through itself the exact count of the datasource contains. Hope that makes sense. So for example, `dvDetails` has a count of 32. When fetch data from the sub report is it iterates 32 times over itself and never touches Detail_Format. What is causing this behavior. Last week this worked perfectly. It would hit FetchData and then detail format to produce a line item, rinse repeat.

From the design side event properties I have "FetchData" pointed to the fetch data listed above. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue that I was having. Apparently just assigning the dataview as the datasource of the sub report was enough. In the datafiled property of the sub report I assigned the column names of the DV as the values. And removed the fetchdata and detailFormat functions from the sub report all together. Since I already had the values I needed in the DV, it just automatically populates.

Comment: +1.  FetchData is used for unbound reports, where one might want to retrieve data from an uncommon datasource and feed the data to the report.  in your case it is easiest to simply bind the controls to the fields in your data source and the report handles everything, no need for code-behind.